# How to select a new added element and edit it?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an `<a>` element:

```
<a id='addNewElementk' onclick='//Some Js Code' class='continueButton'>Click To Add</a>
```

When this anchor is clicked , A new element added:

```
<a href="" class="continueButton">New Added Element</a>
```

And the first anchor which was clicked , Is removed.

I want to select that new element.

I tried:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var newElem = document.getElementsByClassName('continueButton')[1];
    alert(newElem.innerHTML);
}
```

**I'm using `('continueButton')[1]` , As there is another `input` with the same class before that anchor.**

But for sure I get `Click To Add` from the first one , As that's was found when the page is loaded.

So how can I select that new element?

Comment: can you share code snippet for this ?

Comment: you cannot select an element that does not exist. Your element does not exist before the click event occurs. You need to select it when your element is added.

Comment: You're attempting to select the element before it exists in the DOM... You need to run that code within the click event handler of the first `<a>`

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to select the element before it exists in the DOM.

You instead need to run that code within the click event handler of the first `<a>`, like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector('#addNewElementk').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.textContent = 'New Added Element';
    a.href = '#';
    a.classList.add('continueButton');
    a.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      console.log(a.innerHTML);
    });    
    
    this.parentNode.insertBefore(a, this);
    this.remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<a id='addNewElementk' href="#" class='continueButton'>Click To Add</a>
```

Note the use of `addEventListener()` over the outdated `on*` event attributes which should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to select on an element that doesn't exist in the DOM. Dynamically added elements can be accessed in a couple of ways, above someone has an answer that adds an event listener to the created element which is a solid solution. The other most common way would be to use event delegation (if you are familiar with jQuery that would be `$(parentElement).on('action', 'elementWeWantToWatch', function)`) in Vanilla js the pattern is effectively the same, find or make a container element for your dynamic html, then add a listener to that container. Inside the listener you will want to ensure the target matches whatever your dynamic selection would be and execute when you find a match.

#### In this Example

The event listener is initiated on page load to watch the container element. The listener watches for clicks on elements with the `continueButton` class and when it finds one it removes the clicked element and adds a new element (the counter is to demonstrate that new content is being displayed :D)

```js
(function() {
  let i = 1;
  const makeButton = () => {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.classList.add('continueButton');
    a.href = '#';
    a.textContent = `Button ${i}`
    i++;
    return a;
  }
  
  const init = () => {
    const container = document.querySelector('.test');
    container.addEventListener('click', e => { 
      if (e.target.classList.contains('continueButton')) {
        let button = makeButton();
        container.appendChild(button);
        container.removeChild(e.target);
        return;
      }
    });
  };
  
  if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
  } else {
    init();
  }
})()
```

```css
.test {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.continueButton {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius 2px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  line-height: 2;
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 200px;
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<section class="test">
  <a id='addNewElementk' class='continueButton'>Click To Add</a>
</section>
```